# MYSQL Query select only records with latest status as Positive

Tags: mysql

Hi I have a table containing  records of status of each member of an organization. I would like to find out who among the members are still active based on the latest status provided in the table.Hee is a sample of records in the table:

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the last status for each name using a subquery in the `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.name = t.name);
```

You can use an additional conditional expression to determine who is active.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE Status='Active';
```